# My IPhone app is not working when i try to connect with mobile internet connection

Tags: iphone, ios, reachability

when i connect my phone with the WIFI  its working fine, there is no issue in that, but when i change mobile settings to mobile internet connection i am not able to connect with the server getting NO Internet Connection as response from Reachability Class

Comment: Dumb question.  Are you connecting to a server located on you LAN?

Comment: Am not connecting it to LAN

Comment: WiFi is LAN.  How about this, what is the IP Address/Host name you are connecting to.  Does it resolve to 192.168.* or 10.* or 127.*?

Comment: Hi pal, am connecting the app with live server www.***.com , not with 192.168 ....

Comment: @Sparksis, am connecting the app with live server www.***.com , not with 192.168 ....

Comment: What does www.***.com resolve to.  Is it configured locally, are you certain data is set up correctly.  Is the app FTP/SMTP which may be blocked by your ISP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*) Try restarting your device.

*) Settings -> General -> Celular data (On) else

*) Contact your provider....